# sftp get or write file on local machine?

Tags: linux, sftp, jsch, file-processing

I want to download file from remote machine.But its 400MB.I am using get method of JSCH for SFTP. it will take 1-2hour to download?

would writing file using BufferedOutputStream would be more faster.

Comment: I do not see how `BufferedOutputStream` could improve the download speed. + As the first thing you should test and tell us, if you are able to achieve better throughput using any SFTP client.

Comment: I can't do experiment on live server as its client machine.on local machine it takes just 2-3 minutes...

Comment: But until you prove that it's even possible possible to achieve better throughput, you do not have a programming question. - Anyway, 2-3 minutes for JSch or SFTP client?